# I am using the Whisper swift library, is there a way to tell if a whisper is visible or not?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using a [Whisper](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Whisper) in Swift as the following:

```
    let message = Message(title: message, backgroundColor: FlatOrange())
    Whisper(message, to: navigationController!, action: .Show)
```

Is there a way to tell if the Whisper message is currently visible or not?  I'd like to prevent duplicate submissions if an error state is already present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to their documentation it doesn't seem so.  However, you could keep track of a global Boolean, or pass an instance between controllers.

```
If !self.whisperIsVisible {
    // show whisper
    self.whisperIsVisible = true;
}
```